# Splitting posted text using space and inserting into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()==0)
{ // if successfully connected

  $sent_dt=$_POST['scts'];
  // important: escape string values 
  $txt=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['text']);
  $snd=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sender']);

  // creating an sql statement to insert the message into the SMS_IN table
  $sql="INSERT INTO SMS_IN(studentID,lastname,firstname,class) VALUES ('34','Lekan','Balogun','Grade8')";
  // executing the sql statement
  $insert_sms_success = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  // closing the connection
  mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Have recieved some info which are not very clear. I want to be able to split an incoming sms (e.g 32 Lekan Balogun Grade8) using spaces in between to seperate each text as field. What I currently have is the whole sms message. I want to be able to split it using spaces in between the text into my MySql database. Thanks in anticipation as this is my class assignment

Comment: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=php+split+by+space&oq=php+split+by+space&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j65j60l3.5659&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Explode function in PHP to do this quite easily:

```
$yourOriginalText="Splitting posted text using space and inserting into mysql database";
$yourArrayofData=explode(" ", $yourOriginalText);
print_r($yourArrayofData);
```

You can then very easily work out how to insert the right data into the columns you want.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO SMS_IN(studentID,lastname,firstname,class) 
    VALUES 
    ('".$yourArrayofData[0]."',
    '".$yourArrayofData[1]."',
    '".$yourArrayofData[2]."',
    '".$yourArrayofData[3]."')";
```

Be aware though that this will simply take the data in the order it comes in - if someone mucks up an SMS, it will happily continue along. Also as you are passing user data into the database, you really want to do some injection protection.